# MySQL Error Handling within a Transaction

Tags: mysql, error-handling, transactions

I have a procedure which accepts a parameter UserID Varchar(10). If I enter a userID which is longer than 10 characters I get the following message:

call procedure1x('Thisismorethanten'); ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'UserID' at Row 1.

How do i create an error handler for this error so that when it happens, instead of displaying the sentence above, it says something else like "Try again. The UserID is too long."?

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is typically done using `TRY...CATCH` block. MySQL uses `DECLARE ... HANDLER` to handle errors. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html) has some sample blocks that should help you.